# Angular 9 build error for missing peer dependecies

Tags: angular, npm

I have an `npm` module with a **peer dependency** to `electron`: the `require` is inside a function and executed only if needed, so that it can be used both in electron projects and plain javascript projects.

Now I would like to use that module in an Angular 9 project, but when I run `ng build` I get a module not found error.

How can I tell to Angular compiler to "do not care" about the peer dependecy (something like `webpack externals`)? It will never be satisfied and the code requiring it will never be called.

Comment: Angular uses Webpack internally for the build. If you know how to achieve this in Webpack, you might be able to use [custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to modify the Angular Webpack configuration accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @rveerd comment I found this [tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/12/09/angular-webpack) and I have been able to exclude my peer dependency using following webpack configuration file:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  externals: {
    electron: "electron",
  },
};
```